# How to find URL of the current sheet

Tags: google-sheets, links

In Google Sheets, how do I create a hyperlink to *this sheet*?

I have a sheet which I'm about to download as PDF for archive. It would be useful to include a link in the sheet, pointing to itself, so that later I could click the PDF link and open the sheet again.

Of course I could copy the URL from the address bar, and insert the hyperlink:

```
=hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/asdf/edit#gid=0","Link")
```

but I'm looking for a more general method.

Comment: What do you mean by "a more general method"?

Comment: To link to the current sheet, even if the sheet is duplicated and re-used.

Comment: Looks that the [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/93307/88163) by @Max_Makhrov fulfils that requirement. Did you already tried the suggested custom function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open menu `Tools → Script Editor` and paste this code:

```
function getSheetUrl() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SS.getActiveSheet();
  var url = '';
  url += SS.getUrl();
  url += '#gid=';
  url += ss.getSheetId(); 
  return url;
}
```

Close The Script Editor.

And use this formula:

```
=hyperlink(getSheetUrl(),"Link")
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without using the script editor?

Comment: Create the url like this: `#gid=215455` where 215455 is your sheet id. Copy it from the browser address bar.

Comment: Is it possible to do it within a formula, i.e. is there an equivalent of `getSheetId()` which I can call from a formula, without writing or using a script, e.g. `=hyperlink(concatenate("#gid=",getSheetId()),"Link")` ?

Comment: @pts, as far as I know, there's no built-in formula. I'd love to have such formula, too. Hope, Google will implement it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that on the link you provided, there is a `#gid=0` near the end of your link. Just copy this and put it inside the quotation marks.

Example:

```
=hyperlink("**#gid=0**","Link")
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I just get *Invalid link*. Also if I use just "#gid=0" then I get a plausible link to the same sheet, but only when that sheet is open. From a PDF it's a null link. I want to open the sheet in browser, when clicking the link in the PDF one day.

Answer (score 0):

Proposition: (based on @Max Makhrov's [answer](https://jira.eng.netapp.com/browse/CTL-3065))

allowing to both call the function from the script or by precising a sheet name from script like iterating through sheets and building a list of sheet urls.

(That's actually what I'm trying to do and brought me here)

```
function getSheetUrl(sht) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
      url = '';

  sht = sht ? sht : ss.getActiveSheet();

  url = (ss.getUrl() + '#gid=' + ss.getSheetId());

  return url;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the corrections, I'm a bit new to participating on StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

max's answer has a slight typo in it:

```
function getSheetUrl(sht) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),

  var SHT = sht ? sht : ss.getActiveSheet();

  var url = (ss.getUrl() + '#gid=' + SHT.getSheetId());

  return url;
}
```